# Are visitors allowed to enroll in academies (such as a flight training school) in the US under the B1 visa?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, study

I know a person who came to the US under B1 visa (which he says). He says, he is currently enrolled in a flight training school.

I want to know, whether he is allowed to join academies under a B1 visa?

Comment: Note the flight training specifically is actually kind of a special case. Regardless of visa requirements, it actually requires approval from the Department of Homeland Security for a non-citizen to undergo flight training. See [this document from DHS](http://www.dhs.gov/publication/dhs-tsa-pia-026-alien-flight-student-program).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Disclaimer: IANAL, consult your immigration lawyer.
```

Generally **no**, especially if you're asking about academic studies:

> **Is it permissible to enroll in school while in B-1/B-2 status?**
>
> No, it is not.  The regulations, at 8 CFR 214.2(b)(7), specifically
>   prohibit study in the United States while in B-1 or B-2 status.
>
> Before enrolling in classes, individuals who are in B-1 or B-2 status
>   must first acquire F-1 (academic student) or M-1 (vocational student)
>   status.  Enrolling in classes while in B-1/B-2 status will result in a
>   status violation.  Individuals in B-1 or B-2 status, who have violated
>   their nonimmigrant status by enrolling in classes, are not eligible to
>   extend their B status or change to F-1 or M-1 status. These
>   regulations provide no exceptions. [*(source: USCIS)*](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment/special-instructions-b-1b-2-visitors-who-want-enroll-school)

However, allegedly there is a way kind of study legally provided that the course is short, limited to no more than 18 hours a week, and recreational.

> **Requirements to Study on the B Visa**
>
> - Your course of study must be less than 18 hours per week.
> - You must be studying for recreational purposes, not for academic credit.
> - Evidence of sufficient funds to pay for all expected expenses for the duration of your visit. [*(source: Serotte Law)*](https://www.serottelaw.com/Visas/Study/B1Visa.aspx)